# Laravel login strange issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authentication, laravel-5.4

Hello i am new to laravel i made login form using Auth .. when i attempt to login i get redirected to homepage but i use `Auth::check()` it return `false` for example

```
@if (Auth::check())
                <h1>Welcome you are loggeding</h1>
            @else
                <h1>No you are not loggedin</h1>
            @endif
```

So when i login i see **No you are not loggedin** and when i intend to use wrong username or password to make login fails it really fail and return error message **These credentials do not match our records.** But when i login and get redirected to homepage without seeing any error message this means that login is working so how come `Auth::check()` return false and i see **No you are not loggedin**

Even `Auth::user()` return `null` .. i tried almost everything even i restarted XAMPP and removed my browser cache and cookies and removed session files in `storage\framework\sessions`

P.S: the login was working fine until i tried `php artisan session:table` then migrated the table and changed the `SESSION_DRIVER` to database inside session.php and even the sessions table was not actually saving data in it so i rolled back everything when i found that login isn't working anymore i removed the table and changed the driver to file

**.env file**

```
APP_NAME=Eshows
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:wG+6H+MFxNXa2mTw+UPhCkBIXmL5CMCE11sudm51kyE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://eshows.dev/
APP_DOMAIN=eshows.dev

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=eshows
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

**Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /*public function authenticated($request, $user)
    {
        return redirect('/profile/' . $user->username);
    }*/
}
```

**App\User.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'mobile', 'city', 'country', 'about',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

**route\web.php**

```
    //Authentication routes
Auth::routes();
Route::get('logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@logout']);
Route::get('/','Frontend\HomeController@index');
```

**Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        switch($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
                }
            break;

            default:
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/');
                }
            break;
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**view\auth\login.blade.php**

```
@extends('frontend.layouts.master')

@section('body-attrs')
    class="page-template-default page page-id-12 contact-us"
@endsection

@section('csrf-meta')
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
@endsection

@section('csrf-script')
    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>
@endsection

@section('title')
Login to your account
@endsection

@section('styles')
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE STYLE -->
    {!! Html::style('assets/common/css/parsley.css') !!}
    <!-- END PAGE STYLE -->
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="heading-wrapper"><h1>Login to your account or create new one.</h1></div>
    </div>

    <section class="two-columns">
        <div class="container-fluid narrow">
            <div class="row">               
                <div class="col-sm-6 matchHeight column bg-image">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Login to your account</h2><hr>
                    <h4>Explore big community of talented people or begin branding for your own talent to everyone</h4>

                    <article>
                        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'login', 'role' => 'form', 'data-parsely-validate' => '', 'id' => 'wpcf7-f6-o1', 'class' => 'wpcf7 form-validation']) !!}
                            @if (count($errors))
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li style="color:red;">{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            @endif

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <p>
                                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
                                        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                                        <div class="append-icon">
                                            {!! Form::text('username', old('username'), array('class' => 'form-control form-white', 'id' => 'username', 'placeholder' => 'Enter your username...', 'autofocus' => '', 'required' => '')) !!}

                                            <i class="icon-envelope"></i>

                                            @if ($errors->has('username'))
                                                <span class="help-block">
                                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                                                </span>
                                            @endif
                                        </div>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <p>
                                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
                                        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
                                        <div class="append-icon">
                                            {!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control form-white', 'id' => 'password', 'required' => '')) !!}

                                            <i class="icon-lock"></i>

                                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                                <span class="help-block">
                                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                                </span>
                                            @endif
                                        </div>

                                        <br>
                                        <input id="remember" type="checkbox" style="float:left;margin:8px 3px 0 0" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> <span style="display:block;padding-top:3px;">Remember me </span>
                                        <br><hr><a href="{{ route('password.request') }}" style="margin:0" class="forgot-password">Forgot your password?</a>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p>
                                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
                                        <button type="submit" style="color:#FFFFFF;margin-top:15px" class="btn btn-rounded btn-white btn-signup hover-effect">Login to my account</button>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </article>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 matchHeight column bg-image">
                    <div class="create-account">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Create an Account</h2>
                        <h3>Don't have an account yet?</h3>
                        <p>You can create your acount quickly to save your wishlist, your address and other usefull info.</p>
                        <div class="text-center m-t-40">
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="btn btn-rounded btn-white btn-signup hover-effect">Create my Account <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE SCRIPTS -->
    {!! Html::script('assets/frontend/plugins/parallax/scripts/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js') !!}
    {!! Html::script('assets/common/js/parsley.min.js') !!}
    <!-- END PAGE SCRIPTS -->
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it works

```
      class LoginController extends Controller{

protected $redirectTo = '/home';
 ......
 public function authenticate()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works then why Auth::check() return false .. i am using it to show login/rigster links or user profile if logged in but i still see login/register links also Auth::user() return null